# Use Functions to download, parse and filter large App Analytics logs

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits, isv, analytics, salesforce-functions

​Can somebody please help me to assess the feasibility of my solution with Salesforce Functions?

For many years I maintain an **Open Source solution to receive and monitor App Error emails from Managed Packages** called [ISV Cockpit](https://github.com/rsoesemann/salesforce-isv-cockpit). As I learned that [App Analytics Logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_intro.htm) are the future also of Error reporting I wanted to enhance my solution also by pulling those logs. As App Analytics CSV logs also contain a myriad of other information those files are HUGE (depending on the time frame Gigabytes) I cannot download, parse and filter in Apex due to Governor Limits.

And here is where I thought about **Salesforce Functions**. A small Node or Python function that outside of Apex limits, downloads, parses, and filters the CSV down to a sizable chunk of error logs. Which then can be inserted as records in the PBO org.

**Feasible? Sensible? Doable?**

1. Are Functions usable in Scratch orgs already? How?
2. Can I package such a Function in an Open Source Unlocked Package or Managed Package?
3. Will Functions help me overcome the Memory and CPU limits of Apex?
4. Did you stumble across existing code that does something similar?

​

Comment: I'm currently investigating salesforce functions as well to see whether it could be useful for our project. They provide quiet some documentation and even trails already: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/content/learn/trails/discover-salesforce-functions

as for scratch orgs, they explicitly say you can test with that: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/config-org.html